# How to pass aggregate array to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a list in Django views, and I want to pass it to JavaScript for iteration, I've
tried serveral way but seems like the data can't be used by the JavaScript, could anyone have a look,
please?

```
views.py
```

'''

```
def visualisation(request, project_id):

project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

todos = project.todo_set.filter(status='to_do')
progresses = project.todo_set.filter(status='in_progress')
dones = project.todo_set.filter(status='done')

counts_data = Todo.objects.aggregate(
    to_do_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='to_do')),
    in_progress_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='in_progress')),
    done_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='done'))
    )

return render(request, 'todo_lists/progress.html', counts_data)
```

'''

```
html
```

'''

```
data: {
    labels: ['todo','inprogress','done'],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',

        data: [{% for todo in data %} {{ todo }}, {% endfor %}],
        
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

def visualisation(request, project_id):

    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

    todos = project.todo_set.filter(status='to_do')
    progresses = project.todo_set.filter(status='in_progress')
    dones = project.todo_set.filter(status='done')

    counts_data = Todo.objects.aggregate(
        to_do_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='to_do')),
        in_progress_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='in_progress')),
        done_count = Count('pk', filter=Q(status='done'))
    )
    counts_data_json = json.dumps(counts_data)

    return render(request, 'todo_lists/progress.html', {"counts_data":counts_data_json})
```

#### template

```
<script>
    var counts_data = JSON.parse(`{{ counts_data | escapejs }}`);
</script>
<script>
var your_datadata = {
    labels: ['todo','inprogress','done'],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',

        data: counts_data,# you don't need to use the template tag anymore
        
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Im trying to put the list into for loop in html, as u can see above, I used  data: [{% for todo in data %} {{ todo }}, {% endfor %}], but I don’t know how to iterate the list using var counts_data, could u give me more explanation, please?

Comment: I tried data: {{ counts_data }}, but received error ‘didn’t return an HttpResponse object, it returned None instead’, the data is for pie chart in chart.js

Comment: Edited. You don't need to use the template tag anymore. counts_data is now loaded as a javascript variable.

Comment: It still return the same error, "didn’t return an HttpResponse, it returned None instead", any idea?

Comment: Somethinng else must be causing that error. I don't know. `render()` return a HttpResponse

Comment: It's weird but I will check later. The template tag method I used it did return HTTP response, but the data was not right cause the pie chart did not appear as pie chart

Comment: Hi Paul, I solved the HttpResponse error and I tried ur method again, the piechart did not show up, instead, there are 3 small rectangles, same as the method I posted, any idea what happened?